# Euler's proof of Fermat's Last Theorem for cubes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm working through Richard Freidburg's *An Adventurer's Guide to Number Theory*, and on p. 149, chapter 7, he presents Euler's proof of Fermat's Last Theorem for cubes.

He starts with $z^3 = x^3 + y^3$, where $x, y, z$ have no factors in common. This implies that $z$ is even and that $x$ and $y$ are odd.

He doesn't state explicitly, but I think his proof assumes $x > y$.

Because $x$ and $y$ are both odd, $x + y$ is even and $x - y$ is also even.

He defines $p = (x + y)/2$, $q = (x - y)/2$, therefore $x = p + q$ and $y = p - q$.

By substitution, binomial expansion and factoring, he converts $z^3 = x^3 + y^3$ to $z^3 = 2p(p^2+3q^2)$

He then presents 4 'remarks', that the reader should prove. I think I've got 1, 2, and 4 figured out & need help with 3:

*Remark 1:* $p$ and $q$ have no common factor

*Proof:* Suppose $p$ and $q$ have a common factor $a$, then $x = a(p\prime + q\prime)$ and $y = a(p\prime - q\prime)$, therefore $a$ is a common factor of both $x$ and $y$, but $x$ and $y$ have no common factors

*Remark 2:* $p^2 + 3q^2$ is odd

*Proof:* $x = p + q$, $x$ is odd, therefore either $p$ is odd or $q$ is odd. Both cannot be odd, nor can both be even. If $p$ is odd then $q$ is even and $p^2$ is odd, $q^2$ is even and thus $3q^2$ is also even, and $p^2 + 3q^2$ is an odd number plus an even number, hence an odd number. Conversely, if $p$ is even, then $p^2$ is also even, and $q$ is odd, as is $q^2$, thus $3q^2$ is also odd. In this case $p^2 + 3q^2$ is an even number plus an odd number, hence an odd number.

***Remark 3:* $q$ is not divisible by 3**

(Hints provided by the author: For this you must use the fact proven earlier in this chapter, that every cube is congruent to 0, 1 or -1 modulo 9. If $q$ is divisible by 3, then $x \equiv y$ modulo 3, and hence $x^3 \equiv y^3$ modulo 9.)

*Remark 4:* $p$ and $p^2 + 3q^2$ have no prime factor in common, except possibly 3.

*Proof:* Follows from remark 1. $p$ and $q$ have no common factors, therefore $p^2$ and $q^2$ have no common factors. However if 3 is a factor of $p$, then $p$ and $3q^2$ share 3 as a common factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if $x^3$ and $y^3$ are congruent to $0$ mod $9$, then so is $z^3$, which contradicts "no common factors". If they are both $1$ (resp $-1$) then $z^3$ is $2$ (resp $-2$) which contradicts that "cube should be congruent to $0,1,-1$".

Comment: I understand that's the ultimate aim of 'Remark 3'--you have issues with $z^3$ if $x^3 \equiv y^3$ mod $9$. I just don't see how to prove that $q$ is not divisible by $3$.

Comment: If $q$ is divisible by 3, then $x=y$ mod 3 (because $q = x-y$ is divisible by $3$) and so $x^3 = y^3$ module 9. So Either $x^3$ mod $9$ equals $0$, or $1$ or $-1$. In all cases,  you obtain contradiction.

Comment: Hi Peter, I did a bit more thinking on the subject & got the same result by different means: If $q$ is divisible by 3, then: $q \equiv 0$ mod 3, therefore, mod 3, $x \equiv p + 0$ & $y \equiv p - 0$, therefore $x \equiv p \equiv y$.